# UDFs or Probabilistic data structures in a roadmap

Tags: elasticsearch, user-defined-functions, crate

We're interested here in working with high-cardinality indexes. (Which are known to be a problem for Elastic Search)

We already know from you that for

```
select count(distinct high_cardinality_field) from my_table
```

you already have some optimizations to count it.
Will it be possible someday to write something like:

```
select count_via_hyperloglog(high_cardinality_field) from my_table
```

having count_via_hyperloglog as a UDF or something, as it is possible right now in ES via ES-plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in crate this feature is on our backlog as an additional aggregation function which uses the hyperlog algorithm. we plan to do the naming derived from presto http://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html. Your example will then probably look like:

```
select approx_distinct(high_cardinality_field) from my_table
```

However, a possible performance improvement for one specific field per table is to cluster your table based on the high cardinality field as described under https://crate.io/docs/current/sql/ddl.html#routing

Comment: Thank you!  What is a time feeling for this feature to be supported?

Comment: Also generally, would it be possible to write UDFs?

Comment: huh, it is hard to estimate when this feature will make it into a sprint, probably in a month probably

Comment: Currently we have no plugin interface. However contributions are welcome :) take a look at io.crate.operation.aggregation.impl.CountAggregation as an example.

Answer (score 2):

High cardinality counting with HyperLogLog is planned for 1.1.0, the documentation is already up: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Example:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "author_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "author"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for something like UDF, you can use [scripts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), .e.g. by combining a [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) with a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html)

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "in_stock_products": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['price'].value > minPrice"
                    "params": {
                        "minPrice": 5
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_price": {
                    "avg": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes total sense. What is an estimated release time for ES 1.1?

Comment: Looks like ES 1.1.0 has been released 25 of March!